# Why do the colours of my document not change when the button is clicked?

Tags: html, css

I have included my HTML and CSS code. I have inserted some javascript to make my webpage interactive. Can someone tell me why my code is not allowing me to get random colours for my background? I also want the hex code to update to match my random background color when the user clicks the "Get New Color" button.

I have added javascript to my html document, to attempt random colours.

Code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #e74c3c;
  font-family: lato;
}

.color {
  margin-top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

#hex {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 15px;
}

.color button {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2.5px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Random Colors </title>
  <link href="taniaWebsite2.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
  <script>
    alert("Yo Aliens, Click OK to see random colours");
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="color">
    <span id="hex">#e74c3c</span>
    <button onclick="getNewColor()"> Get New Color</button>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getNewColor() {
      var symbols, color;
      symbols = "0123456789ABCDEF";
      color = "#";

      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color = color + symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }

      document.body.taniasWebsite.background = color;
      }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close - just a few minor changes to get this working. First, to update the background style of your page's `body` revise the following:

```
    /* document.body.taniaWebsite2.background=color; <-- Remove this */
    document.body.style.background=color; /* Use this */
```

This is to say *"change the background of the body element's style"*.

The other change needed is to add the missing `}` at the end of your `getNewColor()` function (see comments in code snippet below). Hope this helps!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #e74c3c;
  font-family: lato;
}

.color {
  margin-top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

#hex {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 15px;
}

.color button {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2.5px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Random Colors </title>
  <link href="taniaWebsite2.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
  <script>
    alert("Yo Aliens, Click OK to see random colours");
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="color">
    <span id="hex">#e74c3c</span>
    <button onclick="getNewColor()"> Get New Color</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getNewColor() {
      var symbols, color;
      symbols = "0123456789ABCDEF";
      color = "#";

      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color = color + symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }

      document.body.style.background = color; /* Update this */
      
      /* Add this to update text to match new background color */
      document.getElementById('hex').innerText = color;
    } /* Add this */
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Update

Also, to update the text to match the background color, you can add this to the end of your `getNewColor()` function:

```
  /* Add this to update text to match new background color */
  document.getElementById('hex').innerText = color;
```

Comment: would you possibly know why the hex code text doesnt update as the background changes?

Comment: @tsharma you're welcome - oh yes, we'd need to update the text in that click function.  I've just posted an update to the answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: thank you alot that worked! I'm a beginner with JavaScript. I appreciate the help. Would you possibly know any resources I could use to help me understand JavaScript a bit more?

Comment: yes there are lots of good resources online to learn js - personally I would recommend this as a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: perfect! thank you, greatly appreciate your help. And white arrow is checked:)

Comment: From Paul Irish's site: '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
 for the random hex number.